# How to call more than 2 buttons in onClick event?

Tags: android

I made a class in java which detects when I click a image button(Button A), when that happen, more 8 image buttons become visible. Then when I click in one of this 8 image buttons, my image button A should get the image of the one of the 8 image buttons that I choose.

Its confusing but you will understand better what I want in the code.

```
public void Clicked(View a) {
    op1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    op1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View button) {
            a.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
        }
    });


    op2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View button) {
            a.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imag2);
        }
    });


    op3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View button) {
            a.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image3);
        }
    });


    op4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View button) {
            a.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image5);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This question has not much to do with **javascript**, but is likely related to **java**.

Comment: what u want to achieve?

Comment: i want my parameter a to get a image from one of the ops, but i cant use my parameter a inside of a op1.setOnClickListener

Comment: Declare variable "a" final and it should work.

Comment: where should i declare it?

Answer (score 0):

Change your Methode signature to:

```
 public void Clicked(final View a) {
```

After that you can use "a" in your other listener.

Answer (score -1):

All `OnClickListener` code should go inside `oncreate()`.

I have done it with an option. Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView a;

    Button button;

    Button opc1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_button);
        opc1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_opc1);
        a = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_a);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Clicked();
            }
        });


        opc1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View button) {
                a.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
            }
        });
    }
    public void Clicked() {
        opc1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
}
```